# Shell read from cat line by line into array

Tags: unix, shell

I have a command which outputs something like that:

```
lucid32
lucid64
```

I need to read it into array. So in this particular case I need an equivalent of:

```
boxes =(lucid32 lucid64)
```

I tried to read it like that:

```
boxes=(`mycommand list | tr '\n' ' '`)
```

but it returns $'\033'[0Klucid

How can I fix that?

UPDATED:

it looks like it didn't work because this command outputs a bunch of junk:

```
\r\e[0Klucid32\n\r\e[0Klucid64\n
```

Comment: I wonder if `boxes=(strings <(mycommand list))` will work (assuming bash or a shell that groks process substitution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What shell? Some don't support arrays.

The "junk" you see is terminal control codes for cursor movement or text coloring, etc. It's likely a code to clear to the end of the line.

What command is outputting those characters? Some commands will automatically disable those codes when their output is going somewhere other than a tty. Others have command-line options to turn that off. There are also utilities that will strip the codes for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `boxes=$(mycommand list | tr '\n' ' ')`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
boxes=(`mycommand list | xargs`)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this (in bash):

```
boxes=(); while read l; do boxes+=("$l"); done < <(mycommand list)
```

This will put each output line in a separate array element. While this:

```
boxes=(); while read l; do boxes+=("$l"); done < <(mycommand list | tr "$IFS" '\n')
```

will also separate elements on shell parameter delimiters. This will separate on whitespace:

```
boxes=(); while read l; do boxes+=("$l"); done < <(mycommand list | tr '[:space:]' '\n')
```

It's not as fast as some of the other solutions but you can control how to store the array elements better.